# Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist config Error

Tags: node.js, reactjs, autoprefixer

Getting "Replace Autoprefixer browsers option to Browserslist config." error when running `npm start`. App still starts and works fine, just looking to get rid of this annoying error message. Below is the bottom of my package.json file -- Please let me know if there are more files/details I should include. Thanks!

```
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "npm test && lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "prettier --write",
      "eslint --fix --max-warnings=0",
      "git add"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all",
      "ie 11"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version",
      "ie 11"
    ]
  }
}
```

razzle.config.js:

```
        const postCssLoader = {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: {
        ident: 'postcss',
      }
    };
```

Error:

```
Error: No PostCSS Config found in: /Users/Gabe/esports-calendar/src/client/components/Logo
```

Comment: Are you using autoprefixer or gulp-autoprefixer somewhere in your project?

Comment: The only instance is in my razzle.config.js:
Updated in question

Comment: Yeah, you can remove that autoprefixer config and use `browserlist` in package.json instead. That should fix the warning.

Comment: Ok, I removed the autoprefixer line (Updated to show -- is that done correctly?)
But now I'm getting the error that I added to the question, any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're not using the declared `postCssLoader`, that's where the error comes from.

Comment: Which is strange, this error never arose before removing the autoprefixer line -- are they linked? Sorry I'm new to this all, could you possibly specify where/how I should be using the declared `postCssLoader`? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another hint: have a look at your node_modules. The message also appears if your imports use the old form:

```
cd node_modules
find . -type f | xargs grep -I autoprefixer
```

should work on Unices. Then, write upstream to submit fixes. See also https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/386.